# PHP::MongoCollection->aggregate alternative or fix

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using xhgui and getting this error:

> 127.0.0.1:27017: no such cmd: aggregate

Stack trace:

> /var/www/profiler/src/Xhgui/Profiles.php(172): MongoCollection->aggregate(Array)

**Code:**

```
$mongo = new MongoClient($config['db.host'], $config['db.options']);
$db = $mongo->$config['db.db'];
$results = $db->results->aggregate(array(
    array('$match' => $match),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            'date' => $col,
            'profile.main()' => 1
        )
    )
));
```

Is it possible to fix this error? Maybe need to update mongo extension OR is there any other alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to actually be a problem with your MongoDB instance itself. Aggregation was introduced in version 2.2 of MongoDB, so if your server is running an older version, it won't understand the aggregate() command.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/